# Can anyone figure out what this method (in C) is doing? Trying to understand this for an assignment

Tags: c, methods

```
void* memorycopy (void *des, const void *src, size_t count)
{

  size_t n = (count + 7) / 8;
  char* destination = (char *) des;
  char* source = (char *) src;

  switch (count % 8)
  {
      case 0:  do{  *destination++ = *source++;
      case 7:  *destination++ = *source++;
      case 6:  *destination++ = *source++;
      case 5:  *destination++ = *source++;
      case 4:  *destination++ = *source++;
      case 3:  *destination++ = *source++;
      case 2:  *destination++ = *source++;
      case 1:  *destination++ = *source++;

    } while (--n > 0);
  }

  return des;
}




void tworegistervarswap (int *x, int *y)
{
  if (x != y)
  {
    *x = *x ^ *y;
    *y = *x ^ *y;
    *x = *x ^ *y;
  }
}



int bigintegeraverage (int x, int y)
{
  return (x & y) + ((x ^ y) >> 1);
}
```

Comment: C programmers would generally call that a "function" rather than a "method". Small detail, but...

Comment: @Doug Currie `[homework]` tag probably [shouldn't be added](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60422/is-homework-an-exception/60495#60495).

Comment: I am strongly tempted to close this as it is three questions in one, and I know we've discussed all three of these to at length already. Duff's Device, xor swapping and I don't know if the third one has a name, but you can understand it by looking at the encoding of twos complement integers.

Comment: @alex: Um...the gist of the whole question you linked is a little weak, but tends to [homework] *is* an exception to the meta-tag rule, and the to-add-or-not-to-add discussions have been mixed and pretty fruitless, but tend to ["Yes."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202/2509)

Comment: @dmckee Yeah, the discussion changed a bit since I remembered it. Apologies.

Comment: @alex: I'm not adding myself right now. Mostly because people tend to get defensive about it, but I feel strongly that pedagogical questions are special. Which I guess makes me a wimp.

Answer (score 3):

The horror with `switch` is [Duff's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) (a creatively unrolled loop, but otherwise it just copies source to destination).

`tworegisterswap` swaps the values pointed to by `x` and `y` using bitwise XOR.

`bigintegeraverage` is a sneaky way to get the average of two integers in a potentially non-portable manner but without the possibility of overflow. (See [Aggregate Magic Algorithms](http://aggregate.org/MAGIC/) for details.)

Comment: Or one of the more obscure tricks (that is well known because of its obscurity and guffy name).

Answer (score 1):

It's called Duff's device. It uses `switch` statement to implement state machines in C. In this particular case it performs one branch per 8 iterations of memcopy.

Read this for additional info: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html

The second function swaps two integers.

The third just computes the average of two numbers, because sum can be written as

```
a + b = (a ^ b) + ((a & b) << 1); // the AND here represents carry
```

and by using `((a ^ b) >> 1) + (a & b)` instead of `(a + b >> 1)` we can avoid possible overflows.

Answer (score 1):

See [Tom Duff on Duff's Device](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/duffs-device.html):

> The point of the device is to express general loop unrolling directly in C.  People who have posted saying `just use memcpy' have missed the point, as have those who have criticized it using various machine-dependent memcpy implementations as support.  In fact, the example in the message is not implementable as memcpy, nor is any computer likely to have an memcpy-like idiom that implements it. [more](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/duffs-device.html)

Answer (score 0):

That is actually 3 functions.

`memorycopy()`... well, someone else can figure that one out :P

`tworegistervarswap()` seems to take pointers to two `int`s, and if they don't already match, then it does some bit fiddling with them ([XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR)). It swaps the values without using a temporary variable.

`bigintegeraverage()` takes two `int`s and returns the mean (thanks [Steve Jessop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13005/steve-jessop)) based on them, using bit fiddling as well (AND, XOR and RIGHT SHIFT).

Comment: "returns some values based on them" - the mean. Which is unsurprising considering the name, possibly quite surprising considering only the code ;-)